# Scala filter keys on composed key Map

Tags: scala, filter, hashmap, key, instanceof

I have a map with that structure:

key: an instance of a case class X

value: an instance of a case class Y

X composed of - a:String, b:String, c:String, d:Int (fields)

given b1, c1, d1, i want to filter the map by keys, when:
a can be any string, b=b1, c=c1, d=d1.

means I want to get a map result as an instance of HashMap[X, Y], and filter X only on the 3 fields that I have (b1, c1, d1).

keys that I want can be for example: (a1,b1,c1,d2), (a2,b1,c1,d1)

I tried something like that:

```
      val resMap = givvenMap.filterKeys(key => {
        key.b == b1 && key.c == c1 && key.d == d1
      }).asInstanceOf[HashMap[X, Y]]
```

I need that the field "a" will be a part of the key in the given map.
The map must be immutable!

What can I do?

Comment: You DON'T need a `HashMap`. Just use `Map`. Other than that, your snipped seems fine, except for the nested pair of `{..}` which is completely redundant.  Just get rid of it.

Comment: Complementing Dima, what is the problem you have? Also, note that this wont take the advantages of a **Map**, this still would need to traverse all the elements of the **Map**, if this is going to always be your access pattern you may consider using another data structure.

Comment: I'm new to Scala (came from Java) and I didn't know this syntax (thought that this syntax works only when using pattern matching). I need a hash map for my implementation but it works also. And I don't worry about the traversal, every map can include only a constant number of element in my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You DON'T need a HashMap. Just use Map. Other than that, your snippet seems fine, except for the nested pair of {..} which is completely redundant. Just get rid of it.

A little nicer way to write the same thing is this:

```
    givvenMap.filterKeys {
      case X(_, `b1`, `c1`, `d1`) => true
      case _ => false
    }
```

Note though that `filterKeys` is deprecated (because it is lazy and that causes a lot of confusion), so, you might want to add `.view` before it, and `.toMap` at the end:

```
    givvenMap.view.filterKeys {
      case X(_, `b1`, `c1`, `d1`) => true
      case _ => false
    }.toMap
```

Or better yet just:

```
   givvenMap.collect { case x@(X(_, `b1`, `c1`, `d1`), _) => x }
```